# Random points with maximum spacing constraint in Python

Tags: python

How do I create three random points in Python within a range of 0-49 for x and y (so like a 50x50 "space") with a maximum of only 5 units between all the points. The points cannot be on top of each other.

Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Yes, there are operators you can use, but it doesn't seem a feasible goal. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm asking for three randomly generated (x,y) points that adhere to some constraints: 1)The x value and the y value are both constrained to a range of 0 to 49, 2)The points can have a maximum manhattan distance of 5 between each other 3)The points cannot be on top of each other, in other words, no repeated points

Comment: Yes, and that's easy, but the thing is it doesn't seem possible to check the distance between them.

Comment: Using a distance formula sqrt((x0-x1)^2 - (y0-y1)^2)

Comment: Well, what exactly do you need help on? How far have you gotten? We need some code, please.

Answer (score 2):

This will generate two random points no more than 5 units apart. Can be easily extended for a third point.

```
import random, math
x, y = (random.randint(0,49), random.randint(0,49))

x2, y2 = (100, 100)
while math.sqrt((x-x2)**2 + (y-y2)**2) > 5 or (x==x2 and y==y2):
    x2, y2 = (random.randint(0,49), random.randint(0,49))

print(f'({x},{y}), ({x2},{y2})')
```

Comment: I think they would like random values for all x's and y's.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. Okay.

Comment: Could you edit so it's a little more visually appealing? Such as ```print(f'({x},{y}), ({x2},{y2})')```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work if you don't need it to be super-efficient:

```
import random
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import combinations

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x, y')
dist_under_5 = lambda p1, p2: (p1.x - p2.x)**2 + (p1.y - p2.y)**2 <= 25
while True:
    points = [Point(x=random.randint(0, 49), y=random.randint(0, 49)) for i in '123']
    if all(dist_under_5(p1, p2) and p1 != p2 for (p1, p2) in combinations(points, 2)):
        break
print(points)
# [Point(x=28, y=39), Point(x=30, y=43), Point(x=32, y=39)]
```

Generating random points like this is basically throwing darts over and over in hopes that eventually all 3 will land close to each other. If efficiency is a concern, i.e. you are doing this many times such as for a simulation, then it might be better to narrow the search down after selecting the first point, and then again after the second point. I've refactored the earlier code to show the 2 approaches. Notice that choosing from the reduced set of points is about 100x faster.

```
from random import randint, choice
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import combinations

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x, y')
dist_under_5 = lambda p1, p2: (p1.x - p2.x)**2 + (p1.y - p2.y)**2 <= 25

def get_points_efficient():
    xymin, xymax = 0, 49
    bounds = (xymin, xymax)
    in_bounds = lambda p: all((p.x >= xymin, p.y >= xymin, p.x <= xymax, p.y <= xymax))
    p1 = Point(randint(*bounds), randint(*bounds))
    points_near_p1 = []
    for u in range(-5, 6):
        for v in range(-5, 6):
            if u !=0 or v !=0:
                p_candidate = Point(p1.x + u, p1.y + v)
                if in_bounds(p_candidate) and dist_under_5(p1, p_candidate):
                    points_near_p1.append(p_candidate)
    p2 = choice(points_near_p1)
    points_for_p3 = []
    for p3_candidate in points_near_p1:
        if dist_under_5(p2, p3_candidate) and p2 != p3_candidate:
            points_for_p3.append(p3_candidate)
    p3 = choice(points_for_p3)
    return p1, p2, p3

def get_points_naive():
    while True:
        points = [Point(x=randint(0, 49), y=randint(0, 49)) for i in '123']
        if all(dist_under_5(p1, p2) and p1 != p2 for (p1, p2) in combinations(points, 2)):
            break
    return points

print(get_points_efficient())
# (Point(x=22, y=38), Point(x=18, y=36), Point(x=21, y=40))

print(get_points_naive())
# [Point(x=43, y=35), Point(x=42, y=33), Point(x=39, y=37)]

%timeit get_points_efficient()
# 987 µs ± 67.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
    
%timeit get_points_naive()  
# 112 ms ± 35.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```